# 502 Bad Gateway issue with some containers

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I installed [NGINX Ingress](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress) in the cluster, but when i am trying to access it i am getting 502

These are the steps that i have followed to install NGINX Ingress

```
kubectl apply -f common/ns-and-sa.yaml
kubectl apply -f common/default-server-secret.yaml
kubectl apply -f common/nginx-config.yaml
kubectl apply -f common/vs-definition.yaml
kubectl apply -f common/vsr-definition.yaml
kubectl apply -f rbac/rbac.yaml
kubectl apply -f daemon-set/nginx-ingress.yaml
```

This is the Deployment which i am trying to access from Ingress Controller

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ngtest
  namespace: practice
  labels: 
    app: ngtest
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels: 
      app: ngtest
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels: 
        app: ngtest
    spec: 
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: testkuldeepsecret
      containers:
      - name: ngtest
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:                     
  name: ngtest
  namespace: practice
  labels: 
spec:
  ports: 
  - port: 80 
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: ngtest
```

With the Cluster IP i am able to access the nginx

[image]

Now i configured Ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: practice-ingress
  namespace: practice
spec:
  rules:
  - host: practice.example.com
    http: 
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: ngtest
          servicePort: 80
```

Ingress Description

```
Name:             practice-ingress
Namespace:        practice
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
Rules:
  Host                  Path  Backends
  ----                  ----  --------
  practice.example.com
                        /   ngtest:80 (10.32.0.7:80)
Annotations:
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"practice-ingress","namespace":"practice"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"practice.example.com","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"ngtest","servicePort":80},"path":"/"}]}}]}}

Events:
  Type    Reason          Age   From                      Message
  ----    ------          ----  ----                      -------
  Normal  AddedOrUpdated  46m   nginx-ingress-controller  Configuration for practice/practice-ingress was added or updated
  Normal  AddedOrUpdated  46m   nginx-ingress-controller  Configuration for practice/practice-ingress was added or updated
```

Its clear that ingress will forward it to Port 80 and ngtest service also exposed on port 80

I added IP address and practice.example.com in my host file.

So when i try to access http://practice.example.com i am getting 502

[image]

Ingress NGINX Pod Logs

```
10.32.0.1 - - [14/Mar/2020:07:37:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
2020/03/14 07:37:56 [error] 30#30: *13 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.32.0.1, server: practice.example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.32.0.7:80/favicon.ico", host: "practice.example.com", referrer: "http://practice.example.com/"
2020/03/14 07:37:56 [error] 30#30: *15 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.32.0.1, server: practice.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.32.0.7:80/", host: "practice.example.com"
10.32.0.1 - - [14/Mar/2020:07:37:56 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://practice.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
10.32.0.1 - - [14/Mar/2020:07:37:56 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
2020/03/14 07:37:59 [error] 30#30: *13 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.32.0.1, server: practice.example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.32.0.7:80/favicon.ico", host: "practice.example.com", referrer: "http://practice.example.com/"
10.32.0.1 - - [14/Mar/2020:07:37:59 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://practice.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
2020/03/14 07:43:03 [error] 30#30: *19 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.32.0.1, server: practice.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.32.0.7:80/", host: "practice.example.com"
10.32.0.1 - - [14/Mar/2020:07:43:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
2020/03/14 07:43:06 [error] 30#30: *19 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.32.0.1, server: practice.example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.32.0.7:80/favicon.ico", host: "practice.example.com", referrer: "http://practice.example.com/"
10.32.0.1 - - [14/Mar/2020:07:43:06 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://practice.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
2020/03/14 07:43:09 [error] 30#30: *19 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.32.0.1, server: practice.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.32.0.7:80/", host: "practice.example.com"
10.32.0.1 - - [14/Mar/2020:07:43:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
2020/03/14 07:43:12 [error] 30#30: *19 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.32.0.1, server: practice.example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.32.0.7:80/favicon.ico", host: "practice.example.com", referrer: "http://practice.example.com/"
10.32.0.1 - - [14/Mar/2020:07:43:12 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://practice.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
2020/03/14 07:52:07 [error] 30#30: *25 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.32.0.1, server: practice.example.com, request: "GET /practice HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.32.0.7:80/practice", host: "practice.example.com"
10.32.0.1 - - [14/Mar/2020:07:52:07 +0000] "GET /practice HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
2020/03/14 07:52:11 [error] 30#30: *25 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.32.0.1, server: practice.example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.32.0.7:80/favicon.ico", host: "practice.example.com", referrer: "http://practice.example.com/practice"
10.32.0.1 - - [14/Mar/2020:07:52:11 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://practice.example.com/practice" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
2020/03/14 07:54:48 [error] 30#30: *29 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.32.0.1, server: practice.example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.32.0.7:80/favicon.ico", host: "practice.example.com", referrer: "http://practice.example.com/practice"
10.32.0.1 - - [14/Mar/2020:07:54:48 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://practice.example.com/practice" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
2020/03/14 07:54:58 [error] 30#30: *29 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.32.0.1, server: practice.example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.32.0.7:80/favicon.ico", host: "practice.example.com", referrer: "http://practice.example.com/practice"
10.32.0.1 - - [14/Mar/2020:07:54:58 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://practice.example.com/practice" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
2020/03/14 08:13:36 [error] 30#30: *32 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.32.0.1, server: practice.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.32.0.7:80/", host: "practice.example.com"
10.32.0.1 - - [14/Mar/2020:08:13:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
2020/03/14 08:13:39 [error] 30#30: *32 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.32.0.1, server: practice.example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.32.0.7:80/favicon.ico", host: "practice.example.com", referrer: "http://practice.example.com/"
10.32.0.1 - - [14/Mar/2020:08:13:39 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://practice.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Resources that were running

```
root@ip-172-31-12-0:/home/ubuntu# kubectl get all --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE       NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system     pod/coredns-6955765f44-7fxkh                 1/1     Running   0          6d13h
kube-system     pod/coredns-6955765f44-l7dkf                 1/1     Running   0          6d13h
kube-system     pod/etcd-ip-172-31-12-0                      1/1     Running   0          6d13h
kube-system     pod/kube-apiserver-ip-172-31-12-0            1/1     Running   0          3h2m
kube-system     pod/kube-controller-manager-ip-172-31-12-0   1/1     Running   1          6d13h
kube-system     pod/kube-proxy-2h672                         1/1     Running   1          6d13h
kube-system     pod/kube-proxy-7zc4j                         1/1     Running   0          6d13h
kube-system     pod/kube-scheduler-ip-172-31-12-0            1/1     Running   1          6d13h
kube-system     pod/weave-net-wrrml                          2/2     Running   0          6d13h
kube-system     pod/weave-net-wxjv4                          2/2     Running   4          6d13h
nginx-ingress   pod/nginx-ingress-9hsck                      1/1     Running   0          58m
nginx-ingress   pod/nginx-ingress-xvhfg                      1/1     Running   0          58m
practice        pod/customer-855c6d9bc8-8pq8v                1/1     Running   0          14h
practice        pod/ngtest-6c5ff8c7df-2867b                  1/1     Running   0          46m
practice        pod/some-mysql-7896cfbb4c-zlpl8              1/1     Running   0          38h

NAMESPACE     NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default       service/kubernetes         ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                  6d13h
kube-system   service/kube-dns           ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   6d13h
practice      service/customer-service   ClusterIP   10.110.222.12    <none>        80/TCP                   14h
practice      service/ngtest             ClusterIP   10.105.115.222   <none>        80/TCP                   46m
practice      service/some-mysql         ClusterIP   None             <none>        3306/TCP                 38h

NAMESPACE       NAME                           DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                 AGE
kube-system     daemonset.apps/kube-proxy      2         2         2       2            2           beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux   6d13h
kube-system     daemonset.apps/weave-net       2         2         2       2            2           <none>                        6d13h
nginx-ingress   daemonset.apps/nginx-ingress   2         2         2       2            2           <none>                        58m

NAMESPACE     NAME                         READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system   deployment.apps/coredns      2/2     2            2           6d13h
practice      deployment.apps/customer     1/1     1            1           14h
practice      deployment.apps/ngtest       1/1     1            1           46m
practice      deployment.apps/some-mysql   1/1     1            1           38h

NAMESPACE     NAME                                    DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
kube-system   replicaset.apps/coredns-6955765f44      2         2         2       6d13h
practice      replicaset.apps/customer-855c6d9bc8     1         1         1       14h
practice      replicaset.apps/ngtest-6c5ff8c7df       1         1         1       46m
practice      replicaset.apps/some-mysql-7896cfbb4c   1         1         1       38h
```

Answer (score 1):

`No route to host` means the nginx ingress controller was not able to connect to pod IP. Check if you have any firewall between the node where nginx ingress controller is running and the node where the pod is running.

Comment: Yes node is running and no firewall

Comment: If two pods are their then it works, not able to understand why with one pod its not working

Comment: I think if the pod is running in same node as nginx controller then its working

Answer (score 0):

Did try using https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx?  Most of the time we use wrong ingress.